# How can I get /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/ssl.conf?

Tags: ssl, config, mamp

I followed the tuotorial : http://www.webopius.com/content/355/getting-mamp-working-with-ssl-on-os-x to get ssl certificate. But, I am unable to work on step5 as I could not find ssl.conf in my default MAMP set up. (not even at /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/ssl.conf).

So how can I proceed with editing config file etc? Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That article from webopius is outdated.

Try this tutorial that works for MAMP 2.0.5: 
http://soundsplausible.com/2012/01/14/enable-ssl-in-mamp-2-0-5/

You'll notice that you don't actually need the file /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/ssl.conf, but you'll change the /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-ssl.conf

This tutorial also helps you set up virtual hosts if you haven't done that yet.